# Accessing elements of a struct across field arrays

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct, field

I have a 1 x 1 struct called 'data':

```
 A: [1120x1 double]
 B: [1120x1 double]
 C: [1120x1 double]
 D: [1120x1 double]
 E: [1120x1 double]
 F: [1120x1 double]
 G: [1120x1 double]
 H: [1120x1 double]
 I: [1120x1 double]
```

I can access each element of each field, e.g. data.A(1) but need to access the same numbered elements across the fields without calling data.A(3), data.B(3), data.C(3), etc., individually. Is there a neat way to do this?

Additionally, and this solves the problem too, is there a way of reforming the struct so that the nth elements of each field become a field in their own right, so that the struct now contains 1120 fields each of length 9 (As A-I =9)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html):

```
structfun(@(x) x(3), data)
```

This returns an array that contains 3rd element of each field.