# Summing specific fields in Matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

How do I sum different fields?  I want to sum all of the information for material(1) ...so I want to add 5+4+6+300 but I am unsure how.  Like is there another way besides just doing material(1).May + material(1).June etc....

```
 material(1).May= 5;
 material(1).June=4;
 material(1).July=6;
 material(1).price=300;
 material(2).May=10;
 material(2).price=550;
 material(3).May=90;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of a struct across field arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344239/accessing-elements-of-a-struct-across-field-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `structfun` for this:

```
result = sum(    structfun(@(x)x, material(1))    );
```

The inner portion (`structfun(@(x)x, material(1))`) runs a function each individual field in the structure, and returns the results in an array.  By using the identity function (`@(x)x`) we just get the values.  `sum` of course does the obvious thing.

A slightly longer way to do this is to access each field in a loop.  For example:

```
fNames = fieldnames(material(1));
accumulatedValue = 0;
for ix = 1:length(fNames)
    accumulatedValue = accumulatedValue + material(1).(fNames{ix});
end
result = accumulatedValue
```

For some users this will be easier to read, although for expert users the first will be easier to read.  The result and (approximate) performance are the same.

Comment: +1. Or: `results = sum(structfun(@sum, material(1)))`

Comment: thanks for the reply...is there by chance something simpler than that?

Comment: IMO, the `structfun` version is quite simple.

Comment: @LindsayBaird:  Simpler than a one-liner?

Comment: @LindsayBaird  I don't think that there is a simpler solution.  However, in most cases where I am about to use `structfun` that is an indication that I should rethink my data structures.  That is probably be the case here; hard to tell using the given example.

Comment: @Robert thank you that one is great Pursuit ok i totally get it now thanks for the detailed explanation for the one liner and the loop. yes your right...i think i might have to redo it...thanks for the tip too very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think Pursuit's answer is very good, but here is an alternative off the top of my head:

```
sum( cell2mat( struct2cell( material(1) )));
```